# C++ Crossplatform lightweight file, threading and processing library

Tags: c++, multithreading, process

I'm writing for sometime an wrapper library for my own programming language in C++.
Some of the most important intensions of my library is that it must be fast, easy, portable and lightweighted.

Currently it's depending on the Boost libraries. The problem with the boost libraries is that it's relatively large (file sizes). Also, it's depending on static libraries you have to build yourself. Compared to the prebuilt libraries coming with any native compiler (std), it's lacking on 2 out of the 4 intensions:

- Easy - Users need to build boost itself
- Lightweighted - Boost itself is about 100 MB

I was hoping for some advice, since currently I´m only using boost for purposes std doesn´t provide like threading, file searching and process creation (using unaccepted Boost.Process).

What is the best go for me, stay with boost, writing the libraries myself or maybe you guys know any other good librarie(s) which settle my needs?

**Edit:** This project is being developed with MinGW on Windows, for portability with other platforms (GCC).

Comment: What "file" and "processing" libraries of Boost is it you want to replace? For files it could mean either Boost iostreams or Boost filesystem for example.

Comment: poco? it's quite small IIRC.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Boost.Filesystem (especially for filesearching). And Boost.Process for crossplatform asynchronisly pipe binding.

Comment: There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3335.html) to get the Boost filesystem functionality into the next C++ standard, but I guess workable implementations is still some years away. I know of no replacement for Boost process.

Comment: @Nim Forgot to mention that this project is being developed with MinGW on Windows, for portability with other platforms (GCC). Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: poco is cross platform and I think it's quite modular, so you can take only the bits you need...

Comment: @Nim Thanks for you comments, but it still doesn't support MinGW. Some people managed it, but I can't rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

Since the C++11 standard, C++ have threading built into the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that! Be it's still not a complete solution for my problem.